# Discretization of Multiple Time Series

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, clustering

I'm working on discretizing multiple time series for a project. Here's what I've done so far:

- I concatenated the train signals like this: [1,2,3,5] and [7,3,6,7] into [1,2,3,5,7,3,6,7].
- Then, I trained a K-means ML model with the single, combined signal.
- Finally, I clustered all the signals with the trained model.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach. I chose to concatenate the signals because the k-mean (from scikit-learn) allows inserting only a single dataset, so I didn't know how to feed it with multiple time series.

Has anyone done something similar, or does anyone have suggestions for a better discretization method?